# The recursive result in php's foreach

Tags: php

I have written this code and the result is correct, however its presentation does not show properly; each part is shown in the class "all", but sometimes the next class is called into this part, meaning that before this part (class all) finishes the next part(class="all") begins. the code is brought below:

```
<?php
foreach ($this->list as $data)
{

  if($data['flag']==2){
    echo'<div class="all">
        <div class="article-list">

            <a><img width="190" height="116" title="'. $data['title'].'"  alt="'.$data['title'].'" border="0" class="img-rounded search_image" src="/upload/articles/'.$data['category'].'_3.jpg" ><div class="lablee" style="width: 190px;float: left;text-align: center;position: relative;left: -199px;top: 63px;opacity: 0.8;">Introduction to Islam</div></a>
            <div>
                <div class="title">
                    <a  href="/html/index/intro/cat/'.$data['category'].'">'.$data['title'].'</a>
                </div>
                <div class="description">...' . substr($data['description'], stripos($data['description'], $info['title'])-20, 100) . '...</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>'; }

    else if($data['flag']==1){
    echo'<div class="all">
        <div class="article-list">

            <a><img width="190" height="116" title="'. $data['title'].'"  alt="'.$data['title'].'" border="0" class="img-rounded search_image" src="/photo_gallery/'.$data['category'].'/nor_'.$data['id'].'" ><div class="lablee" style="width: 190px;float: left;text-align: center;position: relative;left: -199px;top: 63px;opacity: 0.8;">Galley</div></a>
            <div>
                <div class="title">
                    <a  href="/html/Gallery/View/id/'.$data['id'].'">'.$data['title'].'</a>
                </div>
                <div class="description">...' . substr($data['description'], stripos($data['description'], $info['title'])-20, 100) . '...</div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>'; }

    else if($data['flag']==0){
    echo'<div class="all">
            <div class="article-list">
                <a><img width="190" height="116" title="'. $data['title'].'"  alt="'.$data['title'].'" border="0" class="img-rounded search_image" src="/upload/articles/'.$data['id'].'_3.jpg" ><div class="lablee" style="width: 190px;float: left;text-align: center;position: relative;left: -199px;top: 63px;opacity: 0.8;">Articles</div></a>
                <div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <a  href="/html/Article/View/id/'.$data['id'].'">'.$data['title'].'</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">...' . substr($data['description'], stripos($data['description'], $info['title'])-20, 100) . '...</div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>';
            }
} ?>
```

Comment: Having trouble parsing your problem. What issue are you facing exactly?

Comment: There's no recursion in here. Also try to reduce your example to something simple by stripping out irrelevant parts. That will make it easier to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I believe the problem is because you have a div inside an anchor tag. Try changing those to spans instead

Comment: Please show us the final HTML code that is displayed in the browser (view source in the browser).

Comment: @Nerdwood thanks, please visit this link, the last 2 parts are destorted.. http://salamislam.com/html/Article/Search/title/Chance/page/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way that you are cutting out part of `$data['description']` for display, the resulting HTML code is malformed. Each description (from the database or wherever it is from) is stored as HTML, so when you cut out 100 characters using the following code, you are getting invalid HTML.

```
substr($data['description'], stripos($data['description'], $info['title'])-20, 100)
```

... has made this description:

```
ost <strong>My Best Chance in years!</strong></span></span></p><p style='margin-left: 0.25in; text
```

... which you can see has ended early (halfway through the `<p>` start tag.

You either need the description in non-HTML format or you need to display the whole description. Maybe you can strip all of the HTML tags out of the description and then display a snippet of it.

### Example of removing the HTML tags

```
//BEFORE the if statement

//Remove HTML tags from the description
$shortDescription = strip_tags($data['description']);

//Get short description snippet
$shortDescription = substr($shortDescription, stripos($shortDescription, $info['title'])-20, 100);

//INSIDE the if statement

//Then you can display the value easily later with less repetition
echo '<div class="description">...' . $shortDescription . '...</div>';
```

Comment: interesting, I've never seen this bug before.can you please tell me how can i define my description which is stored as HTML in my database, in non-HTML format?

Comment: Where is your data coming from?

Comment: from Admin to sql server

Comment: If there is already HTML code stored in the database, you could strip out all of the HTML tags using PHP. E.g. `<p>Text</p>` would become `Text`.

Comment: I use strip_tags! It worked,but I have faced with another problem. the stripos does not work properly. please visit this link: http://salamislam.com/html/Article/Search/title/Chance

Comment: Can you post the value of one of the descriptions before any of the `substr` code is processed? I want to see what the value is before it is modified.

Comment: I search for "live". It should return a line that include "live" string but return "...ve always been there, but I wasn’t able to see you. As if my eyes were blind and I was walking... "//// this link is a descreption: http://salamislam.com/html/Article/View/id/c_51654d2f88bad

Comment: Might need to check the value of `$info['title']`.